# invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' LinqToSql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a program in c# and when I release it and run it in another computer I get an exception:

invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

I installed SqlServer localDB in destination computer

what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you can show us your connection string ??

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\DataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly that exception and fixed it by changing from Framework 4.5 to Framework 4.5.1.  I am using Windows 8.